# Reading and writing structure to binary file in C, then print structure elements

Tags: c, data-structures

I want to write structures into a Binary file in program A, and then read from it in program B, which prints the structures out. However, I am getting incorrect output.

I've tried fwrite in program A, and fread in program B, then subsequently printed the output using printf, only to get a string of nonsense numbers.

Program A:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>

  struct record
  {
    int index;
    char name [100];
    int age;
  };

  int main ()
  {
     struct record *one=malloc(sizeof(struct record));
     FILE *in=fopen("records.bin", "ab+")l

     fgets(one->name, 100, stdin);
     one->index=100;
     one->age=50;

     fwrite(&one, sizeof(struct record), 1, in);
     fclose(in);
  }
```

Program B (all headers and struct the same, with the following code):

```
  int main ()
  {

     FILE *in=fopen("records.bin", "rb+");

     struct record array;

     fread (&array, sizeof(struct record), 1, in);
     printf ("%d\n", array.index);
     printf ("%s\n", array.name);
     printf ("%d\n", array.age);

     fclose(in);

  }
```

I expected the output to be

```
100
j
50
```

But the actual output is `172400800`

Comment: Note, that this method is not portable. This will work if both programs are compiled with the very same compiler with the very same settings on the same platform. But might not work in other conditions. That's because the `struct` and numbers representation (padding, endianess and such) are not necessarily the same for each two platform/compiler combinations.

Answer (score 3):

You're writing trash to your file because you're using the *pointer of a pointer*, not the pointer.

So you can do a quick fix:

```
fwrite(one, sizeof(struct record), 1, in);
```

Or you can rewrite to avoid the allocation, something that's probably a good idea because it's completely unnecessary here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct record
{
  int index;
  char name [100];
  int age;
};

int main ()
{
  struct record one;

  FILE *in = fopen("records.bin", "ab+");

  fgets(one.name, 100, stdin);
  one.index=100;
  one.age=50;

  fwrite(&one, sizeof(struct record), 1, in);
  fclose(in);
}
```

As an additional note, you really should be steering towards variable names that have intrinsic meaning. `one` is not meaningful. `r` is an improvement even if somewhat ambiguous, because at least "r" means something in relation to "record".

Comment: Further, mode `ab+` is not necessary: there is no need for read/write access.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie In this case, no, but it may be part of some kind of code that will eventually read/write like a database might.

Comment: Just `"wb"` would be appropriate, and only `"b"` if you're dealing with old systems. New ones automatically treat all files as binary, and that's the way it should be.